# How can I record the sound output with gtk-recordmydesktop?

Tags: audio, recording

I am using gtk-recordmydesktop to record the video output to my desktop. However, the videos have no sound. All the tutorials I found regarding this involved getting sound recorded from a microphone, while I am interested in getting the sound output recorded. How can I do this? The official FAQ says "The solution is in your mixer's settings. Keep playing with it ;)." which doesn't clarify anything.

How can I get the sound output recorded, while being able to hear it myself also?

Comment: I have created a [video tutorial](http://longterm.softf1.com/2014/blog_resources/Creating_Videos_with_2014_Debian_Linux_video_by_martin_vahi_at_softf1_com_v0.webm) that covers the steps on 2014 Debian Linux.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I managed to get it going with the steps on the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1584849), for clarity here is what I did:

1. `sudo apt-get install gtk-recordmydesktop pavucontrol`
2. Opened the Pulse Audio Volume Control dialog: `Applications > Sound & Video > PulseAudio Volume Control`
3. Opened gtk-recordmydesktop
4. In gtk-rmd advanced preferences, "Sound" tab, set "Device" to `pulse`
5. In gtk-rmd start a recording
6. In Volume Control goto the Recording tab and change the recordmydesktop entry to 'Monitor of '

This is what seems to have worked for me.

Comment: Note: with the 'Monitor of' setting, it should be a carbon copy and you will be able to hear the same audio through headphones etc.

Comment: This worked. FWIW, I had to change the Sound > Device option from DEFAULT to pulse in gtk-recordmydesktop, though that could just be the way Arch was set up beforehand to have a different default.

Comment: @Macha on the command line, this corresponds to passing "--device pulse"

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `pavucontrol`; the recording was initially muted for some reason. Another FWIW, I had to change the profile (configuration tab of pavucontrol) from `Duplex` to `Output`, and that finally did it.

Comment: is there any way to get both the input mic AND the monitor of the audio output?

Comment: Also make sure the check-box near "Sound quality" in gtk-recordmydesktop is marked. It enables/disables audio recording.

Comment: recordmydesktop segfaults as soon as I open pavucontrol on Ubuntu 20.04 :-(

Answer (score 15):

All I had to do was change `DEFAULT` to `pulse` in by: **Advanced** button > **Sound** tab > Device:.

Comment: I confirm that does the trick!

Comment: This isn't *all* I had to do (I also had to do the pavucontrol thing from the other answer), but it was required

Answer (score 5):

If you use Pulseaudio, there is a howto in the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio#Recording%20example%20using%20PulseAudio%20and%20Audacity). It basically boils down to using the pulse audio mixer, to re-route the sound from its source to audacity where it is saved instead of the default output (which would be you speakers).

Comment: Sadly, this sounds like it means I can't hear the sound myself, which isn't good enough.

Comment: @Macha: In principle, I think Pulseaudio is capable of replicating output on several ports. Did you find no way of doing this? Otherwise, a workaround that may or may not be acceptable is to play the sound file as it gets recorded (this may introduce unacceptable latency, and you'll probably have to record to a raw (uncompressed) format).

Comment: @Gilles: Ok, thanks. My bad. The tutorial actually said that, but the way the answer was worded implied otherwise. There is one last problem: This way requires me to manually sync the sound as gtk-recordmydesktop and audacity are started seperately.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use these settings in pavucontrol:

Configuration > Built-in Audio > Profile > Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input

Then it recorded the sound that was playing

Answer (score 1):

The sound is not recording due to low input level. You can fix this from here:

- Go to sound application of settings. Then in there you will see input option adjacent to output.
- You have just to increase the level of input from zero to approx 35-40%. This is the best level as experienced by me.
- Now again go to `recordMyDesktop` app and start your recording.

It will work fine(at least it worked for me).

Answer (score 1):

Changing my sound card device to "pulse" did not work. When I changed it to "default", it worked.

```
Debian, kernel 4.9.0-8-amd64
from lspci -v:
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)         Subsystem: Lenovo Broadwell-U Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48
    Memory at e1230000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Comment: Apparently it's case sensitive... `DEFAULT` did not work for me but `default` did (while on another system, it needed to be `pulse`). Would be nice to know where to look for the correct device name.

Answer (score 1):

**Vokoscreen workaround**

This is the first thing I got working on Ubutu 20.04:

```
sudo apt install vokoscreen
vokoscreen
```

Then go to the audio settings and enable all pulse devices:

[image]

After that it just worked, captured both computer output and my voice on the microphone.

**Kazam workaround**

Kazam has a "Sound from speakers" checkbox that just worked on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
sudo apt install kazam
kazam
```

[image]

Unfortunately the video recording was bugged on Ubuntu 20.04: https://github.com/hzbd/kazam/issues/9

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but here it is for Mint 17.2:

1. Open "Sound Preferences" -> "Input"
2. Choose "Monitor of $YOUR_USUAL_OUTPUT_DEVICE"
3. Record normally in gtk-rmd

This way you can avoid having the input switch recorded in the video.

Just remember to switch it back when you're done!

Comment: This no longer works for Linux Mint. Pulse audio mixer is necessary to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

[image: This setting works for me. Choose Monitors in the Show: in Input Devices]

This setting works for me. Choose Monitors in the Show: in Input Devices

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get `gtk-recordmydesktop` or `kazam` to work, no sound... in the finish I use OBS Studio and it works perfectly

I thought this was self-explanatory as an answer, `gtk-recordmydesktop` and `kazam` are broken, because why would `OBS Studio` work when they do not.  How is OBS different.

For `gtk-recordmydesktop` I have tried installing `qjackctl` and `pulse-module-jack` to enable the jack feature in the program and that results in an immediate `status 256 error`.  Moving on I tried changing `default` to `hw:1,0` and got audio hiss in the background of my recorded video but no actual sound I wanted to record.  I wondered if my system had a problem with ogv so I converted the file to mp4 which is what OBS uses and the converted file still has no sound.

Using `aplay -l` I get a list of my audio device and seems to suggest I need to use `hw:2,0` but that doesn't seem to work either.

Next thing I am trying is to move my audio output to my microphone input with default, hw:1,0 and pulse using the `gst-launch-1.0 pulsesrc ! pulsesink` command after installing `gstreamer-tools`, this doesn't work

Tried fiddling with `gnome-alsamixer`, `projectm-jack` no sound in gtk-recordmydesktop, I have now installed `pavucontrol` and following [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/82297/546389) I can record audio in audacity but am yet to figure out how to get it to work in gtk-recordmydesktp, I got it to work finally by using a setting in `pavucontrol` here is an image of the setting, now it works, apparently I have to do it at least once in each of my recording programs for it to work. gtk-recordmydesktop in its advanced sound tab is now set to DEFAULT

[image]